# $.ajax requests not working on Cordova 5.3.3 Android Application

Tags: ajax, cordova, whitelist

I have a Cordova application in which the first page is a login that does an Ajax request to an external server.

I have added Content-Policy-Security meta tag as follows:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'>`

The Login function gets called and is accessed but the `$.ajax` function seems to be completely ignored.

Before the function is called I've set

`$.support.cors = true;`

In my `config.xml` file I have the following

```
<feature name="Whitelist">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
</feature>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="http://*.nutshellapps.co.uk" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.nutshellapps.co.uk" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

I have added all of the above as a precautionary measure.

The `nutshellapps.co.uk` sub domain is what people will be logging in to with their credentials. So I have added the `http://*.nutshellapps.co.uk` to the access origin.

Is my meta tag correct?

I have a mixture of both inline styles and js, and css/js files containing code.

This worked on the previous version of Cordova that I used (3.5.0), but now this is causing major errors. If i run the application on the browser, it works fine, so I obviously know its the whitelist plugin/a cross domain issue.

Anyone else had this problem?

My ajax call is below

```
$.ajax({
    url: serviceURL + "Json/Authentication/login",
    type: "GET",
    data: {'data':JSON.stringify(loginData)},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The content security policy meta tag that you posted seems to be malformed:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'>
```

There is no closing ".

For Cordova, you also want to have the gap: protocol set and https://ssl.gstatic.com for Android, so I would suggest trying:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;">
```

You could also add connect-src in there if you want to specify different connect hosts versus your default-src.

A blog post that discusses these issues can be found [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).

Comment: Thanks ill check this out tomorrow when I get back to the office in the morning. The blog post helped me understand a lot more about Cordova 5.3.3 so thank you!

Comment: Right I have tested this out and no luck, still isn't working. What would be the result If i added a nonce to my CSP tag?

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  If you attach the Chrome remote debugger to the device whilst it's running the app and refresh the page from Chrome you may see useful errors relating to content security policy in the JS console.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding the following to the top of my index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```

I realise this isn't exactly safe, but I cannot get anything else to work.

Also, I made sure my WhitelistPlugin was loaded as the app started up in my config.xml

```
<feature name="Whitelist">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```